# Expression at html tag vs using controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In angular if I had:

```
$scope.getA= function(){
// do los stuff
return result;
};
$scope.getB= function(){
// do los stuff
return result;
};
$scope.getC= function(){
// do los stuff
return result;
};
//$scope.getD(), $scope.getE()...
```

I have some html elements which "render" depends on a complicate conditions, beside the "readability", is there any performance (render speed) differences at below codes?  I ask this question, because the first one takes longer to display all than second... however I'm not sure if this is really true...

```
    <div ng-if="getA()&&(getB()=="text"?getC():getD())||getE()">hello</div>
//more div tags like this...
```

and

```
    $scope.show = function(){
       var bar = getB()=="text"?getC():getD();
       return getA()&&bar||getE();
    }
    //more functions like this...
    <div ng-if="show()">hello</div>
//more div tags like this...
```

Comment: I would imagine rendering all of the extra characters inside the ng-if attribute on each html element would be the only thing taxing the DOM, which, it very well could be doing that (depending on how many you are rendering) and that might be why it is slower. I have a hard time believing that the difference would be noticeable, though... Anyway, that's my $0.02

Comment: @Claies is there any documentation where explains evaluation of a function in html tag will trigger digest? it makes sense

Comment: that doesn't seem right @Claies that each function causes another digest. They would if different results were returned though. Definitely better to run them once in controller and pass single variable though to view as mentioned

Comment: Would be really helpful to know what's actually your use case. Your code looks a little bit weird, there is probably optimization potential just in logic. On the other hand you may consider one time binding for better performance, if the value wouldn't change.

Comment: @Kossel does my answer was use full for you  ( could add more explanations )?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explains**

[**ngIf directive**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) create a new scope using prototypal inheritance, that means if the attribute isn't found on the **ngIf** scope it will look into it's prototype objects chain for that attribute, that's $scope controlled by you.

Know let's back to your code samples:

```
ng-if="getA() && (getB() == 'text' ? getC() : getD()) || getE()"
```

and

```
ng-if="show()"
```

In first sample while executing **ngIf** would access parent scope **4** times (`getA, getB, getC or getD, getE` functions),

In second sample only once ( `show` function), that's cause performance difference.

**Conclusion**

For your case define method in controller and use it within ngIf directive, but consider possibility to avoid using **ngIf** at all because it will increase $$watcher counts, just perform DOM manipulation(see [angulart.element for more info](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)) **without** increasing $$watcher counts.

Comment: _if you use JQuery just toggle DOM with it_ - and not use angular :-D

Comment: Don't copy the OP's bugs. 'text' should be enclosed in single quotes.

Comment: @georgeawg , thanks! I've updated answer according to your suggestions)

Answer (score 2):

> is there any documentation where explains evaluation of a function in html tag

The `ng-if` directive uses `$watch` to evaluate the expression. <sup>[1](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngIf.js#L89)</sup>

From the Docs:

> ```
>   * @ngdoc method
>   * @name $rootScope.Scope#$watch
>   * @kind function
>   *
>   * @description
> ```
>
> Registers a `listener` callback to be executed whenever the `watchExpression` changes.
>
> - The `watchExpression` is called on every call to [ng.$rootScope.Scope#$digest](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest) and should return the value that will be watched. (`watchExpression` should not change
>     its value when executed multiple times with the same input because it may be executed multiple
>     times by [ng.$rootScope.Scope#$digest](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest). That is, `watchExpression` should be  [idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence).

-- [AngularJS $rootScope.Scope API Reference -- $watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)

> ### $digest();
>
> Processes all of the watchers of the current scope and its children. Because a watcher's listener can change the model, the `$digest()` keeps calling the watchers until no more listeners are firing. This means that it is possible to get into an infinite loop. This function will throw 'Maximum iteration limit exceeded.' if the number of iterations exceeds 10.

-- [AngularJS $rootScope.Scope API Reference -- $digest](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest)